# thymeleaf onclick parameter

Tags: onclick, thymeleaf

I try to pass an object to th:onclick.
When I pass a string(afficherDetails() function), everything is ok
When I pass an object(afficherDetails2() function), in the called function the object seems ok but it is empty.

```js
function afficherDetails(employee) {
   console.log("afficher Details");

   document.getElementById("detailledFirstNameDataLabelId").textContent = employee.firstName;
   document.getElementById("detailledLastNameDataLabelId").textContent = employee.lastName;
   document.getElementById("detailledAddressDataLabelId").textContent =  employee.address;
   document.getElementById("detailledTitleDataLabelId").textContent =  employee.title;
   document.getElementById("detailledManagerDataLabelId").textContent =  employee.manager;
}
function afficherDetails2(name) {
   console.log("afficher Details");

   document.getElementById("detailledFirstNameDataLabelId").textContent = name;

}
```

```html
                <td><button  th:data-parameter1="${employee}" th:onclick=" afficherDetails(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1')) ">details</button></label></td>
                <!--td><button  th:data-parameter1="${employee.firstName}" th:onclick=" afficherDetails2(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1')) ">details</button></label></td-->
            </tr>
```

Is it a correct behavior ? Can't we pass a complex object and we can only pass simple object?

thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You can pass a complex object to a HTML attribute - but it will be reduced to a string by the object's `toString()` method.

Therefore, in your case, an attempt to do the following in JavaScript...

```
var something = employee.firstName;
```

...will do nothing because the function is passed a string not an object - and therefore `employee.firstName` will be `undefined` in JavaScript.

---

**Longer answer:**

Bear in mind a couple of points:

1. A HTML attribute expects to contain a string:

```
<button th:data-parameter1="SOME VALUE IN HERE" ... >
```

So, the attribute `data-parameter1` will be populated by Thymeleaf using a string.

2. All Thymeleaf processing happens on the server. Thymeleaf removes all its processing directives from the template and replaces them with valid HTML. Your JavaScript does not have access to the original Java object - just to whatever *representation* of that object was added to the HTML by Thymeleaf.

---

Let's assume you use something such as:

```
th:data-parameter1="${employee.firstName}"
```

Assuming `employee.firstName` evaluates to a string (`John`) then that is what Thymeleaf will use to produce this:

```
data-parameter1="John"
```

---

But if you try this:

```
th:data-parameter1="${employee}"
```

Assuming `employee` is your custom Java bean, then Thymeleaf will call its `toString()` method to use as the string.

If you have not defined a `toString()` method in your `Employee` class, then the underlying `Object.toString()` method will be used - and you will see something like the following - a string representation of the unique object, based on the object's name and hash code:

```
data-parameter1="org.yourpackage.Employee@bcb8097"
```

You can provide your own implementation of `toString()` in your `Employee` class to provide more useful information. But it has to be a string which can be placed in a HTML attribute.

---

For example, if you pass an `ArrayList` to the button:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John", "Mary");
```

and:

```
th:data-parameter1="${names}"
```

then your HTML button will contain this:

```
data-parameter1="[John, Mary]"
```

because `[John, Mary]` is the result of how `ArrayList` has implemented its `toString()` method.

---

You can send a certain Java objects directly to JavaScript - see [JavaScript serialization](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#advanced-inlined-evaluation-and-javascript-serialization). But that is probably off-topic for this question.

---

One extra note: In the following:

```
th:onclick="afficherDetails(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1'));"
```

You are using `th:onclick` - but there are no Thymeleaf expressions in the attribute, so there is nothing for Thymeleaf to process. You can just use:

```
onclick="afficherDetails(this.getAttribute('data-parameter1'));"
```